# How to use skype as customer service tool

Tags: voip, crm, skype

I would like to allow multiple support engineers to use the same skype account to communicate with customers. This also means multiple simultaneous voice calls with of the support skype account with different customers.

Is this possible, and how can it be implemented.
If not possible, or too cumbersome to be implemented, what are the alternatives? The ideal alternative would be free, and can easily be integrated with my desktop application.

Comment: Why don't you ask Skype?

Comment: And, if this support is IT-related, maybe even multiple screen sharing sessions? http://www.skype.com/intl/en/allfeatures/screensharing/ (To help friends and relatives it's too bad one cannot take control over the other computer using screen sharing. But: screen sharing is cross-platform and I guess I'd not like some support desk to take control over my computer either.) As for the question: is calling back using engineer-specific accounts an option?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this is possible with Skype and wouldn't suggest it if it was.

Try SIP and or any Open VoIP solution, combined with XMPP you should have a fairly open backend that you can cleanly integrate with any website/application and there will be enough libraries and tutorials around to get you started.

Comment: +1 for SIP. If you want a Skype account your customers can call (instead of a phone number), you might want to look at Skype for SIP (http://www.skype.com/intl/en/business/products/pbx-systems/sip/). This will let you connect a Skype account to your SIP server (e.g. Asterisk) - not free though.

Comment: Really good idea! Skype for SIP looks like what I need. Thanks a lot.